# Laravel Authentication additional conditions with another model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Using Laravel's 5.2 Authentication, the docs show that I can add more conditions to an authentication query like so:

**Specifying Additional Conditions**

If you wish, you also may add extra conditions to the authentication query in addition to the user's e-mail and password. For example, we may verify that user is marked as "active":

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1])) {
    // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
}
```

In my case, I would like to set a condition which lives in another many-to-many Eloquent Model:

```
class Account extends Model
{
    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'account_users');
    }
}
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract
{
    public function accounts() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Account', 'account_users');
    }
}
```

There's an account `id` which is passed though a middleware and I access it like this:

`$request->account`

How do I implement the new condition when it refers to a related model? I just don't know how to make use of the ORM relationship. Any help pointing in the right direction is much appreciated!

Comment: You can simply implement that logic/check in the same if statement where you use Auth::attempt(). You can check the related model (assuming it's account in this case)  $request->user()->accounts()->wherePivot('account_id', $request->account);

Comment: @CanCelik you mean as a separate condition in the `if`? Not a part of the `$credentials` param of `attempt()` ?

Comment: that's right. The attempt() method has a third option where you can set false so it will not log the user in if the other condition doesn't meet.

Comment: @CanCelik ok, if you want to write it up as answer I'd be happy to accept.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leverage Eloquent's relationship, you would probably need to add another condition inside of the 'if' control structure, unfortunately. Until your Auth::attempt() is done - there is no Auth::user() object and you need that object for ORM.

Therefore, you could do something like:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
    // Your extra conditions for accounts, just a couple of examples
    if (count(Auth::user()->accounts) == 0) Auth::logout();
    if (! Auth::user()->accounts()->active()->get()) Auth::logout();
}
```